# Comparing a JTable value with other set of JTable values

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablemodel

Anybody can help how to compare the values of a JTable with a another set of values of  JTable?

My program is 
1) Update table from a telnet server
2) When i reupdate, if I find any changes to the table compared to previous one, it should trigger, the row, so that i can update that alone to the backend DB.
3) now i am removing all rows and repopulating. ----> bad approach as i also store logs of it

Please provide your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Each `JTable` has a `TableModel` which provides access to the data behind the `JTable`. You can loop over the data and compare the old values with the new values. This would allow you to update the `TableModel` only where necessary. Do not forget to fire the correct events from your `TableModel` or the `JTable` will become corrupt

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i got a solution for this problem. I hope this is wat I need. Used CollectionUtils [link](http://commons.apache.org/collections/download_collections.cgi) for this.